# start-dfs.sh , Permission denied

Tags: hadoop, ssh, hdfs

```
hduser@ubuntu:~$ start-dfs.sh
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password).
Starting datanodes
localhost: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password).
Starting secondary namenodes [ubuntu]
ubuntu: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
ubuntu: Permission denied (publickey,password).
hduser@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: This isn't a Hadoop problem. You didn't setup a passwordless SSH key correctly

Answer (score 0):

I think  this command will help you

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add
```

restart ssh-agent and do ssh-add.